# Google Maps API directions service

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API direction service to get the distance between two way points. I am also using the places autocomplete. Every once in a while I get crazy results. For example, when selecting two addresses from places that I know are 10 miles apart, I'll get a result like 1603 miles. If I retype and reselect the address, if corrects itself. My code is as follows:

```
// ********************  The Google API  ********************

var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // set up places autocomplete
    var start = document.getElementById('GoogleFromAddress1');
    var startAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start);

    var end = document.getElementById('GoogleToAddress1');
    var endAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(end);

    // add the places auto complete listener for when the values change
    startAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var startAddress = $('#GoogleFromAddress1').val();
        var endAddress = $('#GoogleToAddress1').val();
        if (startAddress)
        {
            $('#FromAddress1').val(startAddress);
        }
        GetGoogleDistance();
    });

    endAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var endAddress = $('#GoogleToAddress1').val();
        if (endAddress)
        {
            $('#ToAddress1').val(endAddress);
        }
        GetGoogleDistance();
    });
}

// use google maps to get the distance
function GetGoogleDistance() {
    var startAddress = $('#FromAddress1').val();
    var endAddress = $('#ToAddress1').val();
    if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
        if (startAddress && endAddress) {
            var request = {
                origin: startAddress,
                destination: endAddress,
                provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    var conversionMetersToMiles = 0.000621371192237;

                    var routeIndex = 0;
                    var distanceMeters = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value
                    // set the map to also show the shortest route by distance
                    var distance = (distanceMeters * conversionMetersToMiles).toFixed(1);
                    console.log((distanceMeters * conversionMetersToMiles).toFixed(1));
                    $('#CalculatedDistance').val(distance);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

[image]

The distance between St Paul MN and Ogilvie MN is about 75 miles.

Anyone else experience this? Since my app will never be used to calculate mileage outside the state in which I live, I thought about just checking if the distance is greater than 500 miles and warn the user to try again.

Comment: Are you sure that it has correctly selected the locations within your state, and not some location elsewhere with the same name?

Comment: Without sharing complete code and examples of failing locations, your question is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using place IDs instead of text values in your directions requests. Once user selects an address from autocomplete you can retrieve the selected place ID. This way you can be sure that you are calculating route between addresses that user selected from autocomplete elements, so it shouldn't produce a mistake.

Have a look at the following example that demonstrates this approach.

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var placeId1, placeId2;      

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
  });
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.5101466,-92.0436835) 
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  
  var inputFrom = document.getElementById('from');
  var autocompleteFrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputFrom, {});
  autocompleteFrom.bindTo('bounds', map);
  autocompleteFrom.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocompleteFrom.getPlace();
      placeId1 = place.place_id;
  });
  
  var inputTo = document.getElementById('to');
  var autocompleteTo = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputTo, {});
  autocompleteTo.bindTo('bounds', map);
  autocompleteTo.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocompleteTo.getPlace();
      placeId2 = place.place_id;
  });
  
}

function calcRoute() {
  if (!placeId1) {
    alert("Please select origin");
    return;
  }
  if (!placeId2) {
    alert("Please select destination");
    return;
  }
  var start = {
     placeId: placeId1
  };
  var end = {
     placeId: placeId2
  };
  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      provideRouteAlternatives: false
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var conversionMetersToMiles = 0.000621371192237;
      var distanceMeters = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value
      var distance = (distanceMeters * conversionMetersToMiles).toFixed(1);
      alert("Distance: " + distance + " miles");
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" placeholder="Select origin" />
<input type="text" name="to" id="to" placeholder="Select destination" />
<input type="button" name="calcroute" value="Get route" onclick="calcRoute();return false;" />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU"></script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ha! I didn't even know there was an ID for places. I will give this a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks!